# Distributed Tensorflow is getting stuck at sess.run()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run tensorflow on multiple machines, multiple GPUs. As an initial step, trying out distributed tensorflow on single machine (following tensorflow tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/distributed/)

Bellow are the lines after which sess.run() stucks

```
import tensorflow as tf
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["localhost:2222", "localhost:2223"]})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="local", task_index=0)
a = tf.constant(8)
b = tf.constant(9)
sess = tf.Session('grpc://localhost:2222')
```

Everything is working fine till here, but when I am running sess.run(), it stucks.

```
    sess.run(tf.mul(a,b))
```

If anybody has already worked on distributed tensorflow, Please let me know the solution or other tutorial which works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Distributed TensorFlow will block until all servers named in the [`tf.train.ClusterSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#ClusterSpec) have started. This happens during the first interaction with the server, which will typically be the first `sess.run()` call. Therefore, if you haven't also started a server listening on `localhost:2223`, then TensorFlow will block until you do.

There are a few solutions to this problem, depending on your later goals:

1. Start a server on `localhost:2223`. In another process, run the following script:

   ```
    import tensorflow as tf
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["localhost:2222", "localhost:2223"]})
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="local", task_index=1)
    server.join()  # Wait forever for incoming connections.
   ```
2. Remove task 1 from the original `tf.train.ClusterSpec`:

   ```
    import tensorflow as tf
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["localhost:2222"]})
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="local", task_index=0)
    # ...
   ```
3. Specify a "device filter" when you create the [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client/session_management#Session) so that the session only uses task 0.

   ```
    # ...
    sess = tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222",
                      config=tf.ConfigProto(device_filters=["/job:local/task:0"]))
   ```